# How can I track a "DatabaseSchemaObjectExistsException" error message?

Tags: debugging

How can I track this error message which is shown when I run drush cron in terminal?

> example@d565:~/www$ drush/drush cron
>
> WD cron: DatabaseSchemaObjectExistsException: Table field_data_field_product_category already exists. in DatabaseSchema->createTable() (line 657 of /home/example/www/includes/database/schema.inc).

I found this: https://www.drupal.org/node/1594138 but I have not enabled the modules:media and file_entity modules

AFAIK: is not drupal core bug but it could related to any other module, problem is that I don't know which one.

The site is using the Drupal commerce module. It is the Commerce Kickstar distribution.

I just run this to find which module is asking for 'field_data_field_product_category? but get nothing at all:

```
example@d565:~/www$ grep -Rin 'field_data_field_product_category' *
```

Comment: Stepping through the code with a debugger is the best possible way - you can't _not_ find it if you do that...it's probably related to fields being deleted then not purged properly, then added again, or various combinations (seen it many times unfortunately)

Comment: not sure how I am going to to solve this since I have no experience at debugging...